# Firestore in Datastore mode does not seem to be strongly consistent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I am using cloud endpoints with objectify and Firestore in Datastore mode. Although it says in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#in_datastore_mode) that all queries are strongly consistent, I have found that they are not in the following examples:

**Example 1**

I made an endpoint that queries for an entity by a property, adds +1 to a `count` property on it, and saves it back to the datastore. I then have 50 different clients all execute that method at the same time. I would expect the `count` property to be 50, however, it usually ends up being somewhere between 25-30.

**Example 2**

I have an endpoint that queries for an entity by a property. If the entity does not exist, I create the entity and save it to the datastore. If it exists, I just return it. Again, I hit this endpoint with 50 different clients at the same time. I would expect there to only be one entity in the Datastore. However, I will have maybe 5-10 of the same entity.

It seems to me this is not strongly consistent. If I take my code in the above endpoints and put them in a transaction with retries, all works as intended. I looked around in objectify to see if there is a [ReadOptions](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rpc/google.datastore.v1#readoptions) set somewhere, but from what I can see, there is not, so it should be using the default of `read_consistency=STRONG`

Comment: The NDB Library automatically caches query results and if you want to make sure you have the latest data (for a scenario like yours), you can turn off cache when you execute the query. Is it possible there is something similar for the Datastore Library (or Objectify)?

Comment: @NoCommandLine From what I read of the Objectify documentation, it does not cache unless you explicitly set it up (which I have not).

Comment: What about the Datastore Library? Maybe it has it. Since the NDB library has it, and NDB is basically a convenient wrapper over the Datastore library, there's the possibility the underlying Datastore library has it

Comment: From the github: `Objectify v6+ uses the Cloud Datastore API` - I think it accesses it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example 1, you need to use transactions to ensure that writes do not stomp on each other.

For example 2, again you need to use a transaction to get consistency across clients.

Strong consistency means that if a client writes a value, it can read or query it back after the write succeeds.  **Not** that if a client reads a value, another reads the same value, they each do a transformation, and try to write that the blinds writes for each client will merge together.

Comment: I thought that strong consistency meant that if client A writes an entity and another client B queries for it via a Query immediately after, the entity will be reflected in the query results. You're saying that it is only the case in the exact same client? So if Client A writes an entity, and then queries for it in the same request, it will be there. This doesn't seem very useful though. I more care about writing an entity and having other users be able to see it right after (instead of having a 1-2 second delay for them). This is how eventual/strong consistency has been described before.

Comment: ... described before in the datastore documentation. So now when the new docs for Firestore say "Queries are no longer eventually consistent. Instead, they are strongly consistent" - it leads me to believe that right after any client writes an entity (or update), any other client will see that write/update immediately after the write succeeds. Can you explain what about my reasoning is mistaken? I feel I am not grasping how the new datastore in firestore mode strong consistency works.